# WPF app.xaml button after click, not back to normal image

Tags: wpf, button, properties, styles

I used this code but after I click the button it does not revert to default style.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<Style x:Key="normalImage" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/SM-Works;component/Images/code_101.png"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="actionImage" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/SM-Works;component/Images/code_10b.png"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="buttonstylesample" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Image x:Name="img" Style="{DynamicResource normalImage}"/>
                            <Border
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <ContentPresenter
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="img" Value="{DynamicResource actionImage}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="img" Value="{DynamicResource actionImage}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="img" Value="{DynamicResource actionImage}"/>
                            </Trigger>

                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

MouseOver, IsPressed is activated, but after push the button, button image is not back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of following trigger:

```
<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="img" Value="{DynamicResource actionImage}"/>
</Trigger>
```

So what is going on is, when you press the button, keyboard focus goes onto the button as well due to which when you release the mouse you will still have `actionImage` style applied. You can verify this effect by focusing out of the button and you'll see the style on `img` will reset to `normalImage` style.